# Open Windows Explorer using Excel VBA referencing path and a cell formula

Tags: excel, vba, path

I'm having problems opening a folder designated by a path and a cell

```
Private Sub cmd_OPEN_FOLDER_Click()

    Dim d As String
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FinalFolder As String

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\ExampleFolder1\ExampleFolder2\"

    FinalFolder = "ActiveSheet.Range(N1).Value" & "\"

    Call Shell("explorer.exe """ & FolderPath & FinalFolder & "", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

If I omit,

```
FinalFolder = "ActiveSheet.Range(N1).Value" & "\"
```

and change,

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe """ & FolderPath & FinalFolder & "", vbNormalFocus)
```

to,

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe """ & FolderPath & "", vbNormalFocus)
```

it works. But if I add 'FinalFolder'. It opens MyDocuments folder. I guess its a default when something isn't working?

Cell N1 has a formula which references another cell on a different sheet. The Formula is "=LISTS!A4". This sheet is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to

```
"ActiveSheet.Range(N1).Value"
```

as

```
ActiveSheet.Range("N1").Value
```

Comment: thanks for your response! I has worked. I thought I tried that. I appreciate your help!